# STLs std::map and std::vector ; checking for object types in a map

Tags: c++, vector, stl, stdmap

So I'm having a problem with fact checking in my program heres the code:
The vector contains 3 types of derived objects I just want a sub total of each base objects in the vector.  I can't seem to find the proper syntax for it either.

```
class Base{
virtual void method() = 0;
}  

class derived_1 : public Base{
    virtual void method();
}
class derived_2 : public Base{
    virtual void method();
}
class derived_3 : public Base{
    virtual void method();
}
class general_class{
private: 
    //objects of derived types have been instantiated into the vector already
    map<string,vector<Base*>> base_map;

    void print(){
        //This line prints the key and size
        cout << iter->first << "    " << iter->.size();

        int d1_count = 0, d2_count = 0,d3_count = 0;

        for(iter=accounts_map.begin();iter !=accounts_map.end();iter++){

            //So I know that the loop iterates through the map
            //how do I fact check to determine which object was found?
            //The below code is incorrect

            if(iter->second[i] == (derived_1 /*"objects"*/)){
                d1_count++;
            }
            if(iter->second[i] == (derived_2 /*"objects"*/)){
                d2_count++;
            }
            if(iter->second[i] == (derived_3 /*"objects"*/)){
                d3_count++;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I'm not sure what the syntax is or the logic behind checking for the correct object type.

Comment: use  dynamic_cast. derived_1 *d1; d1 = dynamic_cast<derived_1>(iter->second[i]); if(d1)  d1_count++;

Comment: BTW, you need another loop. The first loop iterates over the items of the `map`. Another loop is needed to iterate over the items of the `vector`.

Comment: Yeah I just realized that i needed another loop for the vector.  What would be the syntax for going through the vector?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to achieve your goal. You could extend your `Base` interface to return some object kind identificator. Another option would be using RTTI:

```
for(auto pObj : vector)
{
  if(dynamic_cast<derived1*>(pObj))
    d1_count++;
}
```

Note also, that your interface base class is defined incorrectly. You have to provide virtual destructor, otherwise destructors of the derived classes would not be called. Correct version should be:

```
class Base{
    virtual void method() = 0;
    virtual ~Base() {};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(iter->second[i] == (derived_1 /*"objects"*/))
```

There is no direct way to do this. A derived object when taken as a base object, cannot implicitly know it's actual type.

What you can do is, have a virtual method that returns the type-code.

```
virtual void getTypeCode() {
   return 1; //1 for derived_1; 2 for derived_2 etc...
}
```

So you can do this:

```
if(iter->second[i] == 1) { //process derived_1 }
```

There are various idioms and tricks to make the job easier to generate a type code. A common example is the address of a static member.

Comment: Why go through all the trouble when a `dynamic_cast` will do the job?